# Forms Auth - why if I'm allowing all users do I still get redirected to default login.aspx?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, forms-authentication

I have a C# .NET v3.5 web app and I have this in the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

There are no issues, the entire site is publicly available.
If I change the mode forms and do nothing else:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

All pages in the site are redirected to "login.aspx" which does not exist! I assume it is a default setting but if I've not defined a form and allowing all users, why is it redirecting? I am working towards implementing forms security for a subdirectory but I can't get that far because of this weird behavior. There are no other web.config files.

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE:
The issue was an admin had set windows auth via IIS manager and I didn't realize it. Once that was removed and forms auth enabled in IIS manager, forms auth is working in web.config as expected. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Is this an internet or intranet application?  Windows authentication will use the current users credentials.  Forms is different and is local to the application.  So default behavior will be to forward to a login page to handle the Forms Authentication piece.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. It is an internet app. The issue was an admin had set windows auth via IIS manager and I didn't realize it. Once that was removed and forms auth added in IIS manager, forms auth is working in web.config as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
<allow users="*"/>
```

Tells ASP.NET to allow all **known users**. In Windows Authentication that means the default user that your website runs under (IIS_USER, NetworkService, etc). If you are on an intranet, it would be your network login.

When you switch to Forms authentication, all users are unknown and need to be identified (hence the redirect). You can avoid that in Forms authentication by using the "?" marker instead of "*"

```
<allow users="?"/>
```

Which will allow all users into the website, identified or not.